# Uploading large files to SharePoint 2016 hangs up the whole server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

We started to have an issue while uploading large files (> 6 MB) to an on-premise SharePoint 2016.
The whole server stops responding once the file is uploaded to SharePoint (whether thru client application or directly thru SharePoint WebForms).
The only way to recover is to restart the server (hard reset)!

We are unable to capture any logs from the server, as the OS immediately freezes.
The OS is Windows Server 2012 and the SharePoint is installed as a single-server deployment.

Uploading small files (less than 6 MB) is working fine without any troubles.

Any clues?

Comment: `as a single-server deployment.` that's only meant for development. What hardware are you using (RAM, CPU)? SharePoint 2016 doesn't use WebForms either. What are you *actually* doing? Uploading a document to a document library? What client application are you using?

Comment: In any case, this isn't related to programming. This is a SharePoint administration issue, unless you added your own server-side components to handle uploading. In that case you should post your code. SharePoint *does* produce logs automatically. Again, this is an administration issue

Comment: RAM = 36 GB, CPU = 12 Cores  (it's a virtual machine on VM-Ware)

Comment: And the SharePoint logs? Did you check the log locations? And what did you *actually* do? How did you try to upload the document? Again and again though, this isn't a programming question. This should be moved to either `serverfault` or `sharepoint.stackexchange.com`. Even there though, people will ask you for information. Right now, there's none

Comment: Even `The only way to recover is to restart the server (hard reset)!` is ambiguous. Do you mean you have to reset the *host* or the *VM*? If you have to restart the host, check your hardware. A *VM* can't freeze the host, although an overheated CPU can

Comment: Finally, 6MB is small. Even back in 2007, it was a small file. Did you install any server-side code that gets into infinite recursion perhaps? Even that would only peg a *single* CPU.

Comment: Sharepoint Logs show nothing useful. We actually upload the file using the CSOM from a C# webservice. We restart the VM not the host. I already posted the question to stackexchange. Thanks for your help #Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the root cause!
It was the VM storage making all the troubles. Once we moved the VM to another storage, the issue disappeared.